# Using IF to rate an interval value in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have data like this
df:

```
A    rate
10    ...
20
```

How to rate A[] with this rule with the simplest code in R

```
#if A<20  rate=1      if 20<A[]<30 rate=2
```

Thanks

Comment: Read about ifelse.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, perhaps the simplest and most general being `findInterval`:

```r
set.seed(1)

A <- sample(40, 5)

A
#> [1]  4 39  1 34 23

rate <- findInterval(A, c(-Inf, 20, 30, Inf))

rate
#> [1] 1 3 1 3 2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>